# Min and max date between rows - grouping row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datediff

I have a table "A" as in the image and I need to create a view to group data as table "B".
Any suggestions? I'll appreciate every input to improve my skills
Thanks

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXHE.png)

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You show what you've done to attempt this yourself, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Provide your table schemas.  The "HOUR" column isn't really a NVARCHAR datatype is it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT [USER],
      [ACTIVITY],
      MIN([HOUR]) AS [START],
      MAX([HOUR]) AS [END],
      RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(MIN([HOUR]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([HOUR]) AS TIME)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2)+':'+RIGHT('0'+CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(MIN([HOUR]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([HOUR]) AS TIME)) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS [MINUTE]
FROM   TAB_A
GROUP BY [USER],
        [ACTIVITY];
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, but it's not result I need, because grouping activity is wrong way, only one time. I should have min and max date for every interval activity. :-(